# PowerPoint file opens when C# WPF app is running from Visual Studio, but not from ClickOnce published version

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, powerpoint-2010

I have a WPF/C# application. It has a button that runs a particular PowerPoint presentation in slide show mode using the following code:

```
public bool OpenHelpFile()
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.FileName = "powerpnt.exe";
    // the /S option starts PowerPoint in slide show mode
    processStartInfo.Arguments = "/S \"Resources\\Midas 3.pptx\"";
    try { Process.Start(processStartInfo); }
    catch { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

This works perfectly when I'm debugging in Visual Studio (2010), or even when running (not debugging) using the 'Release' solution configuration. However, after publishing the application using `ClickOnce`, the button no longer opens the presentation. Instead, I get this warning:

[image: Error message]

The presentation file is in a folder in the solution named 'Resources' and in its properties window, it has a `Build Action` of `None` and the `Copy To Output Directory` property is set to `Copy Always`. I believe that these settings *could* be the problem, but I'm not sure which options to use. Setting the `Build Action` to `Resource` didn't help because that embeds the file into an assembly from which PowerPoint cannot access the file.

I have also searched the hidden `AppData` folder where `ClickOnce` applications are installed and could not find the presentation file there. The problem *could* also lie with `ClickOnce`. If anyone can shed some light on this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE>>>

I found a solution after reading the page that @Osama Javed's **second** link pointed to... ignore the first link.

As it turned out, all I needed to do was to change the `Build Action` of the file to `Content`. This adds the file into the `Application Files` window (found in the Publish tab of the Project Properties page) where it could be included in the list of deployment files.